# Docker on Windows 10 with Maven

Tags: maven, powershell, docker, windows-10

Try to run docker automated tests with Maven on Windows 10.
There are many issues with Windows 10 and docker.
Our code run great on Mac or Linux.

I run it from the Powershell but getting same issue from terminal (CMD)

It looks like a permission problem with Win10 for local shared folders but I am not sure.

VirtualBox 5.0.6

Docker version 1.8.2, build 0a8c2e3

The Maven plugin

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

This is the error:

```
[ERROR] ←[31mDOCKER> invalid mode for volumes-from: /opt/myapp (Internal Server Error: 500)←[m
[ERROR] ←[31mDOCKER> Error occurred during container startup, shutting down...←[m
```

did anyone come across this error on Windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

So after a long few weeks of rebuilding windows back to 8.0, 8.1 and 10 there are few tips for anyone trying the same tricks.

The error is because Docker doesn't have permissions to the drive I was running maven from.

1. Download VM and Git independently. When installing docker unselect the two from the automatic override.
2. dont install Kitematic. It doesnt work most of the time
3. Docker user has access to the user folder only, normally under C:Users\your-name/... you should run all mvn commands from that folder or sub-folder
4. docker ver 1.8.3 or later
5. Win 10 works well, CMD & Powershell. I personally prefer powershell as it have more features.
6. Make sure to close the VM properly after a session before reboot

   > docker-machine stop (instance)
7. I normally add 2 CPU and 8GRam to my VM, it makes Docker run faster and less likely to crash when running few containers. Like 8 mysql instances.

good luck!